# why won't my character with the rig move?

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

I made a basic TABS model for my first model and wanted to rig it. I followed many tutorials but no matter what I do the character won't move with the rig. Where only 2 instances where it did work (kinda)

1. if I turn on bone envelopes which isn't really a solution
2. when I scale up the character and rig and then add automatic weights which will for some reason lead to the character also shrinking [image: for some reason it srinks the model]

I tried redoing the rig, making a rig using rigify etc.nothing seemed to work[image]

here is the blender file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U2zm3tueuc1XkO41nGONfsaoOorvZrax/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale of both the two objects, parent *With Automatic Weight*, it works:

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean
when you say two objects do you mean the rig and the model?

Comment: sorry but I still don't understand
when i try to parent the rig, "automatic weights doesn't pop up

Comment: How exactly do I do that
sorry for being a bother but I'm pretty new to blender

Comment: Select your character, press Ctrl A and apply the scale, do the same thing for the armature. Now select the character, shift select the armature, press Ctrl P and choose the With Automatic Weight option

Comment: Thank you so much!